# Bash starting with colon and aposthrope. Meaning

Tags: bash

I'm runing a bash script like this, with dev as an argument:

Here i print env and it shows dev

```
: '
role.dev=root
role.qa=user1
role.prod=user1
role=role.${env}
'
```

At this point role is empty

I never saw starting with colon and aposthrope and not sure how to work with it. I have to do it like this because there are some projects with this approach but it's not working in my case. Any idea?

Comment: Colon is just a command that doesn't do anything, and apostrophe is the string delimiter. There's nothing special about putting them together, they both do their normal thing.

Comment: This is basically just commenting out all those lines of the script by putting them inside a string.

Comment: Ok but which would be the reason to get role empty?

Comment: Because the assignment to `role` is commented out.